# What is the best way to re-level wall tile?

Tags: tile, level

I'm installing tile on a wall in my bathroom. After about ten rows of tile have been installed above my ledger board, the tiles have drifted slightly unlevel along the horizontal plane. To clarify, they are evenly deep up against the substrate, but as I hold a level across the top of the tiles, they are higher on the left than the right by about 1/8". I'd like to fix this so I can keep my tiles level as I move upwards during the next phase of installing more rows of tile.

So my question is, **what would I use to adjust the next row of tiles**? I am using a spacer and wedge system. What kind of substance/material should I use to shim up each tile, gradually, so that the new row becomes perfectly level (perfectly as possible)? Of course one wouldn't want the shim to stick out beyond the depth of the incoming grout.

Should I use toothpicks?... I would greatly appreciate advice from professionals who have encountered this issue in their prior experience.

Answer (score 1):

Two choices:

One: remove 3 or 4 from the high end and re-position them lower, best option...

Two: pack the low end up with spacers. Once dry, remove spacers and grout between the tiles.

I found that laying a straight edge across the tiles while the adhesive was still soft allowed tiles to be adjusted and the line kept straight.

There are X or + spacers available which can be used the the corners - designed to fit in the corner between 4 tiles, But they can be used by putting 1 leg in the gap so two legs sit on the tile faces and the 4th leg is the handle to remove...